# How to make a list of associative array in yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, yaml, associative-array

I'm trying to store some configuration variables in yaml represented as an associative array aka dictionary.
Here is how I did:

```
content_prices:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  - {country: AU, price: 6990000}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  - {country: AT, price: 4990000}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  - {country: BE, price: 4990000}
```

This produce an exception when I try to parse it from my ROR init files:

> undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for nil:NilClass

Here is how I init it:

```
Config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/prices.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
```

I guess my yaml syntax is wrong, then how to write it properly ?

Comment: I don't see sections for rails envs in your YAML

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Your YAML looks okay, or you can configure an array of hashes like this :

```
content_prices:
  - country: AU
    price: 6990000
  - country: AT
    price: 4990000
  - country: BE
    price: 4990000
```

Which will load as the following hash:

```
{"content_prices"=>[
  {"country"=>"AU", "price"=>6990000}, 
  {"country"=>"AT", "price"=>4990000}, 
  {"country"=>"BE", "price"=>4990000}]}
```

But that still doesn't give you any reference to the `Rails.env` in the main hash. The problem seems to be what you're expecting to be in your hash rather than the format of the YAML.

Comment: I guess, this is inline approach `key:
  - string1` , `key: ['string1', 'string2',` and this is contemporary object notation for associative where the above syntax is not accepted , ```- { param1: 'myvalue', param2: 'myvalue2' }```  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136212/3419535  , https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814618/3419535

Answer (score 15):

Not on rails, but on Symfony2 php, I had to configure the yml file like this:

```
content_prices:
  - 
    country: AU
    price: 6990000
  - 
    country: AT
    price: 4990000
  - 
    country: BE
    price: 4990000
```

Comment: This is an issue with the symfony parser that does not respect the specification of lists unless there is a newline after the dash

Comment: @dreftymac is this issue fixed now? Could you give a link to the bug report?

Comment: @marcv if my memory serves me correctly it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone wants to use dynamic keys, it is also possible:

```
AppBundle\Service\MailerService:
    lazy: false
    arguments:
      $defaultFrom:
        '%mailer_user%': '%mailer_name%'
```