# YAML Multi-Line Arrays

Tags: yaml

In [YAML](http://yaml.org/spec), you can easily create [multi-line strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines). However, I would like the ability to create a multi-line array (mainly for readibility within config files) using the `|` character.

A YAML **array** can be represented as: `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`.

A YAML **sequence** uses a dash followed by a space and then a string:

```
- String1
- String2
- String3
```

This would evaluate to: `['string1', 'string2', 'string3']`.

A YAML **mapping** is an array of key and value pairs that we see all the time in YAML:

```
Key1: string1
Key2: string2
Key3: string3
```

This is all well and good, but I can't for the life of me see how to do a multi-line array. Something like this:

```
|
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
['string4', 'string5', 'string6']
```

Short of creating multiple array mappings in YAML and merging them in my programming language of choice, is there any way to achieve multi-line arrays, maybe with `{ }` like Python has but in YAML?

Comment: honestly, whats a multi-line array & when should it be meaningful at all? Rather than just the looks of your code

Comment: Having to scroll across the screen horizontally to see all the options rather than see them all one one screen at once.

Comment: Multi-line may make diffs much more readable, since every item added or removed corresponds to 1  line added or removed.

Comment: @XedinUnknown Good technical argument and reasoning - version control usage is impacted less with future changes. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

A YAML **sequence** *is* an **array**. So this is the right way to express it:

```
key:
  - string1
  - string2      
  - string3
  - string4
  - string5
  - string6
```

That's identical in meaning to:

```
key: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6']
```

It's also legal to split a single-line array over several lines:

```
key: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 
  'string4', 'string5', 
  'string6']
```

and even have multi-line strings in single-line arrays:

```
key: ['string1', 'long
  string', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6']
```

Comment: is it an issue if the strings start with a - (e.g. options passed in the command line)? do I then have to quote? `  - "-myarg"`?

Comment: That depends totally on whatever program you're using to parse the YAML. This question is just about the YAML specification.

Comment: i did not know that YAML could handle brackets like that. thank you :-)

Answer (score 88):

have you tried this?

```
-
  name: Jack
  age: 32
-
  name: Claudia
  age: 25
```

I get this: `[{"name"=>"Jack", "age"=>32}, {"name"=>"Claudia", "age"=>25}]` (I use the `YAML` Ruby class).

Answer (score 20):

If what you are needing is an array of arrays, you can do this way:

```yaml
key:
  - [ 'value11', 'value12', 'value13' ]
  - [ 'value21', 'value22', 'value23' ]
```

Comment: Thanks Vinicius, but the question explicitly stated: ".I would like the ability to create a multi-line array", not multiple lines of multiple arrays.

Comment: didn't realize the question wasn't exactly mine, but came for this - thanks @Vinicius

Answer (score 10):

The following would work:

```
myarray: [
  String1, String2, String3,
  String4, String5, String5, String7
]
```

I tested it using the snakeyaml implementation, I am not sure about other implementations though.

Comment: it worked with Puppet Enterprise 3.7 hiera yaml (Ruby yaml) one thing I find ruby yaml is quite sensitive too is the identation, and avoid using tabs. so example above should be like in two lines idented same number of spaces where first line is `myarray:  [String1, String2, String3,`
and second line is `    String4, String5, String5, String7 ]  `

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me and its good from readability point of view when the number of array element values is small:

```
key: [string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6]
```

This has been tested to work with `snakeyaml` and `ruamel.yaml`.