# Where can I define the Input for grails.util.Holders.config in grails 4.0.1

Tags: grails

In grails 2.0 I could define Lists in Config.groovy and access them via grails.util.Holders.config.

What is the corresponding feature in grails 4.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

> In grails 2.0 I could define Lists in Config.groovy and access them
>   via grails.util.Holders.config.

The best answer depends on knowing some context about from where you want to access the values but in general, you shouldn't use `Holders.config` (that is true in Grails 2, 3 and 4).  One option you have is to let the DI container inject the `List` of values for you.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/user3647093configlist.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/user3647093configlist/blob/7078c5edc896afd6afb0280f126794730485c564/grails-app/conf/application.yml#L1-L7

```
---
music:
    drummers:
        - Neil Peart
        - Mike Portnoy
        - Bill Bruford
        - Carl Palmer
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/user3647093configlist/blob/7078c5edc896afd6afb0280f126794730485c564/grails-app/init/user3647093configlist/BootStrap.groovy

```
package user3647093configlist

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

class BootStrap {

    @Value('${music.drummers}')
    List<String> drummerNames

    def init = { servletContext ->
        println 'Drummers:'
        for(String name : drummerNames) {
            println "\t$name"
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

That outputs the following on application startup:

```
Drummers:
        Neil Peart
        Mike Portnoy
        Bill Bruford
        Carl Palmer
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Config class: https://docs.grails.org/4.0.1/api/grails/config/Config.html

And according to official docs: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments

> Grails supports the concept of per environment configuration. The
>   `application.yml` and `application.groovy` files in the `grails-app/conf`
>   directory can use per-environment configuration using either YAML or
>   the syntax provided by ConfigSlurper.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand .yml syntax. in Config. groovy of grails 2 I simply wrote a line kommunikationsart=['Festnetz','Handy','Fax','eMail','Homepage'] and got it as a list in my domainclass by  Holders.config.kommunikationsart. My simple question is now: what ist the corresponding .yml line and how to access it from my domain class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657086/yaml-multi-line-arrays

Answer (score -1):

simply added 2 lines at the end of .yml

```html
registrierungsstati: [beantragt, in Prüfung, anerkannt] 
qualitätsnachweise:[Techniker,Bachelor,Master,Diplom,Promotion]
```

and retrieved them as lists in my domain Class

```
List getQualitätsnachweise () { 
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    grailsApplication.config.getProperty('qualitätsnachweise')
}

List getRegistrierungsstati () {
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    grailsApplication.config.getProperty('registrierungsstati')
}
```

see also
https://objectcomputing.com/news/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values-grails-3

Comment: Thi sis a bad idea.  The way the code is written, `grailsApplication.config` will result in `NullPointerException` because you have not initialized the local `GrailsApplication grailsApplication` variable.  Even if you fixed that, this is not a great approach.  A better idea is to let the DI container inject the config values into your class instead of your class reaching out to get the config values.

Answer (score -1):

Correction:

```
List getQualitätsnachweise () { 
GrailsApplication grailsApplication = Holders.grailsApplication
grailsApplication.config.getProperty('qualitätsnachweise')
```

}

```
List getRegistrierungsstati () {
GrailsApplication grailsApplication = Holders.grailsApplication
grailsApplication.config.getProperty('registrierungsstati')
```

}

grailsApplication has to be initialized in both cases with Holders.grailsApplication, the same error is also in
https://objectcomputing.com/news/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values-grails-3

By the way it is no good Idea to use a getter for generating the List in a domain class, because hibernate comes in trouble with it, because hibernate takes the getter as a database field. Therefore I used

```
static List qualitaetsnachweise ()
```

instead of

static List getQualitaetsnachweise ()

And be careful:
 grailsApplication.config.getProperty('qualitaetsnachweise')
does not come as a list, You'll get it as a comma separated string, that you have to convert by

... .split(',').toList()

Comment: "the same error is also in https://objectcomputing.com/news/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values-grails-3" - I am not able to generate an error using the approaches I wrote about in that article.  That looks like it works as expected.

Comment: `static List qualitaetsnachweise ()` - You really should not have a `static` method in a domain class to retrieve config values.  There are no use cases where that is going to be the best approach.

Comment: "And be careful: grailsApplication.config.getProperty('qualitaetsnachweise') does not come as a list.." - If you really want to reference `config.getProperty`, you should use the overloaded version which accepts a type as a parameter.  For example, `grailsApplication.config.getProperty('qualitaetsnachweise', List, []) `.