# Load yaml config with array type

Tags: rust

I am writing a code where I am trying to load config.yaml file

```
impl ::std::default::Default for MyConfig {
    fn default() -> Self { Self { foo: "".into(), conf: vec![] } }
}
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyConfig {
    foo: String,
    conf: Vec<String>
}

let cfg: MyConfig = confy::load("config")?;
println!("{:#?}", cfg);
```

Config.yaml file

```
foo: "test"
conf:
        gg
        gb
        gg
        bb
```

Output

```
MyConfig {
    url: "",
    jobs: [],
}
```

I have kept the config.yaml file in the same folder where it is getting called. It looks like it is not able to load the file itself. What is getting missed there?

EDIT: When I changed the extension from yaml to toml, and provided full path, it found the file but the structure is expecting is

config.toml

```
foo = "test"
conf = ["gg","gb","gv","gx"]
```

full path

```
confy::load("c:/test/config")?;
```

Tried multiple places to keep it but not getting it, looks like it requires full path.

But I got the output

```
MyConfig {
    url: "test",
    jobs: [
        "gg",
        "gb",
        "gv",
        "gx",
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While David Chopin's answer is correct that the YAML is not right, there is a couple of deeper issues.

Firstly, while it is not really documented, looking at the `confy` source, it expects TOML formatted data, not YAML - for simple cases they can be similar I think. (Turns out this is not 100% correct - the [github page says](https://github.com/rust-cli/confy#using-yaml) you can switch to YAML this using `features = ["yaml_conf"]` in the `Cargo.toml` file)

Secondly, I'm guessing the root problem is that `confy` is not finding your configuration file.

The docs for [`confy::load`](https://docs.rs/confy/0.4.0/confy/fn.load.html) state:

> Load an application configuration from disk
>
> A new configuration file is created with default values if none exists.

So, I think it's looking somewhere else, not finding your file and instead of erroring creating a nice default file in that location then returning that default for you.

Comment: Yes, I thought to be using yaml since I searched for this but it is expecting toml file with the same structure, but it is not able to load file in same folder without path, I had to give full path to load it. Thanks for you time

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be formatted as follows:

```yaml
foo: "test"
conf:
        - gg
        - gb
        - gg
        - bb
```

Comment: It is giving the same empty result

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657086/yaml-multi-line-arrays/33136212

Comment: Looks like it is not expecting yaml file, only toml ones, but when I searched for yml library, I found confy so trying the same. Also it was not able to load the config file, I gave full path, then it loaded. Thanks for your time