# docker-compose.yml dash syntax in YAML

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

In the `docker-compose.yml` files, why are certain enumerations done with a dash `-`, and others without?

```
services:
  web:           # the enumeration of [build, ports, volumes, environment] doesn't use a -
    build: .
    ports:             
      - "5000:5000"     # why the - here?  could we remove it and have ports: "5000:5000"?
    volumes:
      - .:/code         # why the - here?
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development        # why no - here?
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Another example:

```
version: '2'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql                # could we remove this - prefix?
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress        # no - in this enumeration, why?
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db                            # would it be ok without - ?
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - ./wp:/var/www/html            # same
...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Dashes represent Lists.

> All members of a list are lines beginning at the same indentation level starting with a `-`

```yml
# A list of tasty fruits
- Apple
- Orange
- Strawberry
- Mango
```

No Dashes Means that they are Key Value Pairs to a Dictionary.

> A dictionary is represented in a simple `key: value` form

```yml
martin:
  name: Martin D'vloper
  job: Developer
  skill: Elite
```

According to the Docker Compose Documentation at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

```
environment:
  RACK_ENV: development
  SHOW: 'true'
  SESSION_SECRET:
```

is the same as:

```
environment:
  - RACK_ENV=development
  - SHOW=true
  - SESSION_SECRET
```

Notice, that docker doesn't care which one you use in the `environment` key , as long as they are consistent. Docker-compose syntax just happens to define it that way.

Comment: Thanks! I notice we can replace a multiline dash enumeration with `volumes: ["element1", "element2"]`.

Comment: Yes, they are the same, lists, they've been specified in the YAML syntax reference I linked in the answer above.

Comment: Be careful that -SHOW="true" will consider the quotation marks as part of the string.

Answer (score 3):

The dash in YAML denotes an array of elements (values only).
The other syntax in YAML, of `key: value` is a dictionary (key-value pairs).

So, for example, `ports` is an array of values, with one value: "5000:5000". The `:` here has no significance from the YAML standpoint.

As another example, and clarification about the `environment` directive in docker compose:

The `environment` definition in fact supports two formats.

When defined like this:

```
environment:
  KEY: value
  KEY2: value2
```

it is a YAML dictionary of key-value pairs.

When defined like this:

```
environment:
  - KEY=value
  - KEY2=value2
```

it is an array of values, and once again, the `=` here has no significance from YAML standpoint, it is passed as is to the consumer that processes it (docker-compose binary in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This comes directly from [YAML syntax specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax).

- Dashes/hyphens denote (unnamed) list elements, thus in the format `-<value>`
- Entries without dashes are named child elements, format `<name>: <value>`

Answer (score 0):

After further tests, I noticed that

```
volumes: ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

fails with:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

so it's either:

```
volumes: 
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

or

```
volumes: ['./mysql:/var/lib/mysql']
```

according to [YAML Multi-Line Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657086/yaml-multi-line-arrays/33136212#33136212).