# update yaml array using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following yaml which I want to replace the command field

Have

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test004
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "eee"
          image: "test"
          command: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

want

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test004
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "eee"
          image: "test"
          command: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

```bash
yq  -i n --style  myfile.yaml 'spec.template.spec.containers[0].command' "["a", "b", "c","d"]"
```

is there a way to achive this with `yq`, I try with style without success, If I change it to simple string it works, but not when I want to pass full array, any idea ?

Comment: @Inian -  version 3.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the field `[+]` notation to [append fields in yq v3](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/commands/write-update#adding-new-fields). So your command results in

```sh
yq --style double w -i myfile.yaml 'spec.template.spec.containers[0].command[+]' "c"
```

The above command appends the entry `"c"` to the array.

Or if you want to update the whole array `command` you could do in v4. Note that this creates the array entries in separate lines than what is shown in the OP. See [YAML Multi-Line Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136212/5291015)

```sh
yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command |= ["a", "b", "c","d"] | ..style="double"' yaml
```

---

Note that yq v4 is already out there and supports much powerful path expressions and operations. See [Upgrading from v3](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3) for instructions

Comment: Thanks, regard the first option, how does it know to put it in the third place of the array?

Comment: @RaynD: Just specify the index to insert on i.e. `command[2]` instead of `+`

Comment: Thanks i've tried it and it work however it delete third entry "d", any idea how to add and not delete ?

Comment: @RaynD: Am afraid you can't do that with `yq` v3 or v4

Comment: so maybe add "c" and "d" , is it possible ? but each as new item

Comment: or maybe replace the all value with new value but type array ? `["a", "b", "c","d"]` ?

Comment: again, no support to append an array in v3 atleast, can you upgrade to v4?

Comment: what do you say,  is it possible in version4?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but got and error, please see my update

Comment: @RaynD: Did you upgrade your yq version to latest?

Comment: @RaynD: You missed the `.` before `spec`. In v4 it is needed

Comment: thanks I try it like this `yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command |= ["a", "b", "c","d"] | ..style="double"' -i deployment.yaml` and the file gone mass, does it works for you?
`

Comment: does it works for you? i've provided the file in the question

Comment: @RaynD: Your original attempt had the `[0]` notation. Seems like it is not needed. See update

Comment: thanks but when I remove the 0 I got error : Error: Cannot index array with 'command' ...

Comment: @RaynD: It works for the YAML you pasted in the question. If you are testing this on a different YAML, post that to the question.

Comment: Sorry I think when I copied it some properties wasn't aligned, I put the link with the exact file, could you please have a look as I got error : `Error: Cannot index array with 'command' (strconv.ParseInt: parsing "command": invalid syntax)

`

Comment: @RaynD: With the current input `yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command |= ["a", "b", "c","d"] | ..style="double"'` works.

Comment: Thanks it works but the problem it add to other properties `""` e.g. before i've `containerPort: 6565` after I run the command it become `containerPort: "6565"` , any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: Again, where is `containerPort` in your YAML

Comment: Sorry, I didnt want to put all the file since its long but please have a look on this https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb05aa0c   , `continarport` and `compose.cmd` values are changed .

Comment: @RaynD: Can't get this to work myself - have raised a bug report - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/722

Comment: @Inian Can I pass a bash array variable to this command instead of hard coded arrray ["a", "b", "c","d"] ?