# Pull Request is not detecting action when run via workflow_run

Tags: github, continuous-integration, pipeline, github-actions

I have 2 workflows in my repository:

```
name: First

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
   
    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: 1.16

    - name: Test
      run: go test -v ./...
```

and

```
name: Second

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["First"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  golangci:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}

    name: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: golangci-lint
        uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2
        with:
          version: latest
```

The second workflow is launched only when the first workflow successfully completes. This part works.

I have set branch rules so that any pull request on "master" must have these 2 workflows pass. When I make/update a PR both the workflows run as expected. However the PR never detects that the 2nd workflow has run.. it gets stuck in the "Expected — Waiting for status to be reported" state.

I assume this is because the 2nd workflow is not triggered by a pull request, but by the previous workflow. Is there a way I can make my 2nd workflow notify the correct pull request that it has completed?

(this is a trivial example that illustrates a problem that occurs on a much larger repository with multiple workflows, it would not be ideal to have all jobs in one workflow in the large repo).

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to point the checkout step like this: `with: ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}` or `${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_sha }}` but nothing seems to work either

Answer (score 2):

The `workflow_run` does not show the PR check list, but GitHub supports reusing workflow [^1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows)

I wrote a [small demo](https://github.com/bxb100/action-test) for your case

```
name: stackoverflow-68759990

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  first:
    name: pretend the First workflow
    uses: bxb100/action-test/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow-A.yml@main
   
  second:
    name: pretend the Second workflow
    needs: first
    uses: bxb100/action-test/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow-C.yml@main
```

the config like this:

```
                       +---------------------------+
           +-----------+ event: pull_request[main] +----------+
           |           +---------------------------+          |
           |                                                  |
           |                                                  |
           v                                                  v
+------------------------+                        +--------------------------+
| stackoverflow-68759990 |                        | stackoverflow-68759990-1 |
+---+--------------------+                        +---+----------------------+
    |                                                 |
  jobs                                             workflow_run
    |       +------------------------------+          |       +--------------------------+
    +------>| reusable-workflow-A.yml@main |          +------>| stackoverflow-68759990-2 |
    |       +------------------------------+                  +--------------------------+
    |
    |       +------------------------------+
    +------>| reusable-workflow-C.yml@main |
            +------------------------------+
```

`workflow_run`: `stackoverflow-68759990-1.yml` trigger `stackoverflow-68759990-2.yml`

`reusing`: `stackoverflow-68759990.yml` trigger `reusable-workflow-A.yml` then `reusable-workflow-C.yml`

When you PR, you can see the `stackoverflow-68759990-2` not showing below

[image]

you can echo the `workflow payload` to prove that had been triggered [^2](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#:%7E:text=head_branch%2C%20and%20head_sha.-,workflow,-object)

[image]

Comment: Just to add a clarification to this answer: `68759990-1.yml` is followed by `68759990-2.yml` via `workflow_run`. The above screenshot doesn't prove whether `68759990-2.yml` actually ran, but assuming it did, it wasn't connected to the PR as otherwise we'd see an entry for `second / actions-tagger (workflow_run)`. The reusable workflows that are called by `68759990.yml` would be visible if you clicked into either of the two jobs and looked at the steps, but they're not their own workflows, they're just steps of `68759990.yml`.

Answer (score -1):

My issue was referring to the main branch's workflow in a 'uses' statement. The following code got the action seen and triggered:

```
jobs: 
  MyJob:
    uses: my-org/my-app/.github/workflows/deploy-workflow-dry-run.yml@my-feature-branch
```

If I didn't have the `@my-feature-branch` specified or if I had @main, it would not show up in running actions. I only put 'my-feature-branch' above to sanity check that it works, as we obviously can't keep using the name of a specific branch.  Before I merge it, I will have it point to main, so I suppose we'll have to force merge it in the first time.

Answer (score -2):

I think the way you are specifying the **master** branch is not correct. I think you should try like this in your work flow:

```
on:
  # Trigger the workflow on pull request,
  # but only for the master branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
```

Ref: [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#example-using-multiple-events-with-activity-types-or-configuration)

Comment: Tried but no difference at all which is expected as both are correct yml syntax for arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136212/6355024. Plus the workflow does execute on the provided branch, the issue is with the PR