# Symfony passing array of arguments to DI services via yml file

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml, symfony-2.3

I'm using symfony 2.x and I have a class which accept and array of configurations from yml file

config.yml

```
services:
  my_di: 
    class: \MyClass
    arguments:
      - param1: 'myvalue'
```

MyClass.php

```
class {

public function __construc(array $configs = []) {

 var_dump($config);

}
```

Output (this is working correctly)

```
array (size=1)
   param1 => 'myvalue'
)
```

But I want to pass one more value to the same array via yml
- param2: 'myvalue2'

and the exprected output will be

```
array (size=1)
   param1 => 'myvalue',
   param2 => 'myvalue2'
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not try to add a second array element?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply use a yaml array in your `config.yml` file:

```
services:
  my_di: 
    class: \MyClass
    arguments:
      - { param1: 'myvalue', param2: 'myvalue2' }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the following syntax (don't put a dash `-` at the beginning of each row of your associative array):

```
services:
  my_di: 
    class: \MyClass
    arguments:
      $configs:
        param1: 'myvalue'
        param2: 'myvalue2'
        param3: 'myvalue3'
```